# Jquery calculation with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys got a problem hopefully you can help,

```
var imageHeight = $("#slider > Img").height();
var imageFloat = (imageHeight + 31 / 2);

alert(imageFloat);

$("#slidernavright").css("marginTop",(imageFloat));
```

Can anyone see the issue here, the alert on `imageFloat` is bringing back a value of 15.5 which means the `imageHeight` is not being accounted for, The variable `imageHeight` is working and retrieving the correct number of the height image, also the margin is working and the `div` tag is being moved down by 15.5px. Dont know much about jQuery, I think this is just a syntax issue.

Comment: Have you tried with a lower case I ?
$("#slider > img").height();

Comment: So if you replaced alert(imageFloat); with alert(imageHeight);, it produces a number other than 0?

Comment: alert(imageHeight); produces the value of 241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the `img` isn't fully loaded, so its `height` is `0`.

To fix it, put an `onload` handler on the `img`. And also, check to see if it is cached using the `.complete` property, and of so, invoke the handler manually.

```
$("#slider > Img")
    .on("load", function() {
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        var imageFloat = (imageHeight + 31 / 2);

        alert(imageFloat);

        $("#slidernavright").css("marginTop",(imageFloat));
    })
    .filter(function() { return this.complete; })
    .trigger("load");
```

And keep in mind that `/` has higher precedence than `+`, so this:

```
var imageFloat = (imageHeight + 31 / 2);
```

is doing this:

```
var imageFloat = (imageHeight + (31 / 2));
```

instead of this:

```
var imageFloat = ((imageHeight + 31) / 2);
```

Comment: this is working as such but imageHeight is producing the value of 991 which is like the size of the whole document and not the size of the #slider > Img

Comment: @AaronProwse: Did you try my updated answer? I made it simpler. `$(this).height()` should give you the height of the image.

Comment: working thanks mate :) much appreciated! is there away of adapting this so that the imageFloat is dynamic and updated everytime the image size changes without refresh? because the slider image basically stretches to the screen so is that possible to have the margin top adjusting for browser size change difference without refreshing?

Comment: @AaronProwse: You mean like if the user adjusts the window size? If so, then put a `"resize"` handler on `window` that runs the same code. It will run as the user resizes the window.

Answer (score 1):

Are you computing this before or after `window.onload`? If the image hasn't completely loaded yet, jQuery can't retrieve the height.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var imageHeight = $("#slider > img").height();
  var imageFloat = (imageHeight + 31 / 2); // perhaps you meant (imageHeight+31)/2 ?
  $("#slidernavright").css("marginTop",imageFloat);
};
```

Comment: erm not too sure but tried this didnt work I am loading the document like this                                                           ?$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#slider > Img#1").fadeIn(500);
 startSlider();
 sliderControl();
 controlHeight();
 });

Comment: The document is ready before the images are loaded - you have to wait for the window to load. You can also tie it to just the image load, but there are tricks to be careful of; window.onload is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you SURE imageHeight is being calculated properly? I just tested it with `imageHeight = 5` and it worked fine for me, even without the order of operations stuff.

Answer (score 0):

try using something like `parseInt()` -- `var * = parseInt(imageHeight);`

This will give the actual int value, usually when you get values like this .height() they return the string representation of the value and not the actual int value. I had an issue with this a few days ago.